# Show listView.Items in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, listview, combobox

How can I show the listView.Items on Form2 in a ComboBox on Form1, and I want to use all data (subitems) from the selected Item.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
Form1.comboBox.Items.AddRange(
    Form2.listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(a => a.Text));
```

This will simply copy the text of the `ListViewItem` to the combo box.

For all subitems, it gets a bit more complex:

```
Form1.comboBox.Items.AddRange(
    Form2.listView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(
    a => string.Join(", ", a.SubItems
        .Cast<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
        .Select(s => s.Text).ToArray())).ToArray());
```

This uses LINQ to get an array of text values from the subitems of each item to be joined together with `", "`, and adds each concatenated string list to the `ComboBox`